# Listen Laravel migration events

Tags: php, laravel, events, migration, listener

Laravel Migration event listeners doesn't work.

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [ App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class, ....
```

**app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Listeners\DeleteUnitsImagesFromAws;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsStarted;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        MigrationsStarted::class => [
            DeleteUnitsImagesFromAws::class,
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Event::listen(MigrationsStarted::class, function($event) {
            \Log::channel('payment')->info(['class' => 'DeleteUnitsImagesFromAws']);
        });

    }
}
```

The above logs are not working, but the following is working.

```
namespace Illuminate\Database\Events;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Events\MigrationEvent as MigrationEventContract;

class MigrationsStarted implements MigrationEventContract
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        \Log::channel('daily')->info(['class' => '1000']);
    }
}
```

How should I listen this event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solved***

I've compared my project code and fresh Laravel code.
The reason was overridden **MigrationServiceProvider**  .
there missed **events** parameter when creating **Migrator** class.
Here the changed / working class

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Migrator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MigrationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('migrator', function (Application $app) {
            return new Migrator(
                $app->make("migration.repository"),
                $app->make("db"),
                $app->make("files"),
                $app->make('events')// missed in old code
            );
        });
    }
}
```